# What is the mistake in rsplit for python 3?

Tags: python, string

Code snippet in python 3:

```
t = rsplit('/opt/archival/single_download_urls/0fc7632a3028f4de0529d01bf9c87110/[92, 91, 86]','/',1)[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'rsplit' is not defined
```

Why does this give name error for rsplit? I have upgraded the code from py 2.7 to 3.6 after which I face this error

Comment: [`rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) is a method on the string type. So you should call it on a string.

Comment: You should have a look how `.split()` works [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below code, `rsplit` is a function of the string class, that's why it's `str.split`, which means that you need to do `<some string here>.rsplit(<inputs here>)`:

```
t = '/opt/archival/single_download_urls/0fc7632a3028f4de0529d01bf9c87110/[92, 91, 86]'.rsplit('/',1)[1]
```